# nfs, systemd and automount (ultimate issue involves restarting mounts in containers w podman)

Tags: fedora, systemd, nfs, podman

Fedora linux 36

I have mounts of the following form in /etc/fstab:

```
192.168.1.101:/volume1/video /mnt/synology_video nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,intr,comment=systemd.automount 0 0
192.168.1.101:/volume1/music /mnt/synology_music nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,intr,comment=systemd.automount 0 0
```

when the machine boots up, systemctl will show me the status of the mounts as follows...**notice the status of "waiting"**:

```
mnt-synology_music.automount                     loaded active waiting   mnt-synology_music.automount
mnt-synology_video.automount                     loaded active waiting   mnt-synology_video.automount
```

I have a podman container running jellyfin server, which is to be restarted using podman-start that's set up in the unit file as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Podman Start All Containers With Restart Policy Set To Always
Documentation=man:podman-start(1)
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target mnt-synology_music.automount mnt-synology_video.automount 

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
Environment=LOGGING="--log-level=info"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman $LOGGING start --all --filter restart-policy=always
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/podman $LOGGING stop $(/usr/bin/podman container ls --filter restart-policy=always -q)'

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

the podman container itself is using volume mounts (-v option) to mount to those filesystems on the host machine (maybe this is the part i need to change, to mount directly instead?).

however, when the container tries to restart it fails **exactly once per each mount, then succeeds** with an error about symbolic links.  I am not using any symbolic links:

```
Error: OCI runtime error: crun: error stat'ing file `/mnt/synology_music`: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

As the container hits each mount, **or if I just manually `ls` the mount**, systemd's status magically changes to **running**.   an `ls` of the directory now lights up the mounts and it's clear that they previously were not actually "connected", and were waiting for something to touch them:

```
  mnt-synology_music.automount                      loaded active running   mnt-synology_music.automount
  mnt-synology_video.automount                      loaded active running   mnt-synology_video.automount
```

There appears then to be some additional level of "wait until something actually touches the directory before starting the nfs mount", and it is preventing my container from cleanly restarting.   As the container stats each filesystem, systemd magically **actually** starts the mount and then it works, however, this prevents automatic restart from working.

I cannot find any option to affect this behavior.  I actually saw a comment somewhere about just doing `ls -l` to start them, that's insane.  I need the things to be running automatically and it seems nuts I'd have to script an `ls -l` command to do it.

how to solve this problem correctly ?

Comment: Would it be an acceptable tradeoff to use a regular mount point instead of an automounter? It looks like the container's attempt to access the filesystem doesn't trigger systemd's automounting logic, so the two seem to be incompatible.

Comment: it would.  how do I do that?    It seems like when systemd is around it takes over these things.

Comment: Removing the `comment=systemd.automount` part from `/etc/fstab` and rebooting the system should do the trick. I would also suggest adding `noauto` so that the system doesn't have a hard dependency on the NFS share at boot time. You can then add the resulting standard mount units to the Podman unit's Wants/Requires.

Answer (score 2):

okey doke, thanks community, the answer is to [create a podman volume to the nfs mount directly](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-volume-create.1.html), that way the container hits the podman volume and podman does the mount.

im using ansible so this looks like:

```
- name: mount same volumes with podman too
  containers.podman.podman_volume:
    state: present
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    options:
      - "type=nfs"
      - "o=rw"
      - "device=192.168.1.101:{{ item.path }}"
  with_items:
    - {"name": "synology_music", "path": "/volume1/music"}
    - {"name": "synology_video", "path": "/volume1/video"}

# later, run container

- name: run container
  containers.podman.podman_container:
    image: docker.io/jellyfin/jellyfin:latest
    name: jellyfin
    recreate: "{{ force_container_rebuild|bool }}"
    restart_policy: always
    privileged: yes
    capabilities:
      - NET_ADMIN
    published_ports:
      - "{{ jellyfin_service_ip }}:8096:8096/tcp"
      - "{{ jellyfin_service_ip }}:8920:8920/tcp"
      - "{{ jellyfin_service_ip }}:1900:1900/udp"
      - "{{ jellyfin_service_ip }}:7359:7359/udp"

    volumes:
      - "{{ infrastructure_path }}/jellyfin/config:/config:Z"
      - "{{ infrastructure_path }}/jellyfin/cache:/cache:Z"
      - "synology_video:/video"
      - "synology_music:/music"
```